# The Meaning Behind the Cross Validation Score in Factor Analysis

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

In order to choose the best number of underlying factors for my data using factor analysis, I decided to use the tutorial outlined in [scikit-learn's documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_fa_model_selection.html).

Running `cross_val_score(fa, X)` outputs a score (usually a negative number). What is this score actually measuring? Any references with your answer would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The score you get is determined by the estimator you use. In your case this is [Factor Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis). Looking at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.html#sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis) of the algorithm, you can find the explanation:

> FactorAnalysis performs a maximum likelihood estimate of the so-called loading matrix, the transformation of the latent variables to the observed ones, using expectation-maximization (EM).

and the reference:

```
score(X[, y])   Compute the average log-likelihood of the samples
```

So your number is the logarithm of the [maximum likelihood estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) of the [factor loading matrix](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/0470011815.b2a13026).